# PodioConnectionError ~4/5 times on every API call w/ PHP Library

Tags: php, podio

We are getting this error ~4/5 times from the Podio PHP Library:

```
PodioConnectionError: Connection to Podio API failed: [6] Could not resolve host: api.podio.com; Name or service not known
```

This happens on any API call as far as I can tell.

I have not found any helpful information directly related to this. I know the "[6]" indicates curl_errno 6, which is: *"Couldn't resolve host. The given remote host was not resolved."*

However, I cannot find anything that helps diagnose how/why that is happening, and the error seems to me to indicate that the api.podio.com server is not responding to our requests. Any help regarding this issue would be hugely beneficial. It's particularly frustrating as it works sometimes (1/5 times), which makes it very hard to diagnose since it's not always happening...

Comment: Try to eliminate server connection problems first. Try pinging that API from the server for a prolonged period of time to see if there are connectivity issues.

Comment: How quickly is the code making calls to their API?

Comment: @vuryss I had a ping going for a couple hours the other day, never saw a dropped  packet.

Comment: @castis For a test I had the PHP script, simply authenticate with Podio, and do a single "Get Item" call, and return those results. I just tried doing it 10 times again, and I waited 5-10 seconds between each attempt. It threw this error all 10 times.

Comment: Do you get that error for auth call or for get item call? Please ensure your network is working fine, there were no errors on Podio side recently, all servers were up and working stable.

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio I believe i've seen it happen on the auth call as well sometimes. Are there some other network settings that could cause an error this? Like I said, it is pinging no problem, and since it works sometimes the network isn't down completely.

Comment: Possible issues setting up https connection? (Like: it's timing out while negotiating ssl version or something like that). I'm 99% sure it's something with your network setup.