# Podio API calls fail with "404 - Not found"

Tags: api, authentication, http-status-code-404, podio

I have scripts failing when **executing calls to the Podio API returning an error**:

> "404 - Not found"

This **happens mostly the first 2 to 5 times** I run a script calling the API.
Most of the times (but not exclusively) it happens during the authentication call (the first API call of the script).

If I keep trying, then **after an undefined number of attempts.... it works without any issue**.

The behaviour is really weird, unpredictable and is slowing down the ability to try my code.

- I've checked the http://status.podio.com/ page but it reports no disruption (this is happening consistently in the last 2-3 days).
- I verified that I am not being limited; the rate-limit is not hit (header shows about 240/250 hits available).
- I verified my connection; it is stable, and latency & bandwidth are average and sufficient to interact with the API.

I keep getting 404 on paths that totally exist and that work few seconds later.

Is there any disservice happening?
What else can I verify?

Please, help.

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973835/podioconnectionerror-4-5-times-on-every-api-call-w-php-library) but not a duplicate.

Comment: Citrix Podio should be more clear on their customer support model over StackOverflow. – Tagging as *"podio"* doesn't seem help much: **1 & half month passed** and ["podio" page is desolate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/podio?tab=active&pagesize=50). – Is there a better way to request support from Podio Team?

Comment: Citrix does not provide official support for the API (best efforts only). SO is community support. If you're getting 404 errors you probably have an issue in your code. Why don't you post it for us to see?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the support model. The issue disappeared when I came back to a more performant connection. Apparently a 150-250ms response (`ping`) time was the reason that makes the authentication fail. Even though this does not explain while following attempts might work. Unfortunately I don't have access to the previous connection anymore, to confirm this.